# Whatsapp Chat DataSet DataMining Project

Tags: facebook, dataset, chat, whatsapp, facebook-messenger

I want a dataset of whatsapp chats for my project. Can anyone provide me any link to it. I am interested particularly in whatsapp chat data or facebook messenger chat data.

Comment: You mean you want to back up (download) all your WhatsApp data: all dialogs and all messages?

Comment: No actually i want some dataset of chats between different people. I am interested in any chat log if it is available online

Comment: Got it. Do you want to train some neural network? Please specify. There are some publicly available dialog sets, so I will be able to share something. Depends on what you need it for

Comment: I am not sure if i need a neural net for my task, But any chatting dataset is helpful (preferably whats app or facebook messenger chats)